# MSDOS command(s) to copy files matching pattern in directory structure to local directory

Tags: command-line, batch-file, dos

I have a job that periodically runs and archives files into a folder structure that looks like this:

```
ArchiveFolder
    TimestampFolder
        JobnameFolder
            job<timestamp>.xml
```

For a given job, I'd like to collect all xml files in the archive folder into a flat directory (no subdirectories, just all the files) without having to drill down into each one, examine for the proper job, then copy the file.

It seems there should be a fairly straigtforward way of doing this.  Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** I guess I wasn't clear here.  The TimeStampFolder will have a name of something like `2011-07-24`, the JobnameFolder will have a name like `FooFeed` or `BarFeed`, and the job file will have a name like `job2011-07-24.xml`.  There are hundreds to thousands of TimeStampFolders, and each one may have one or more job folders in it.  Given a specific job name, I want to collect all the files in all the directories that match that job type, and dump them into the local folder, with no subdirectories.

Comment: to ensure clarity: you specify a job name, it goes into each `TimestampFolder` and pulls any file that includes that job name?

Comment: it goes into each `TimeStampFolder`, looks for a folder with the job name, goes into that folder, and pulls out the file... actually, in some cases, it may be multiple files, but if I can figure out how to do singular files I'm sure multiple files won't be so difficult.

Comment: so the job<timestamp>.xml file is of no importance? As long as we specify a jobname, go into the folder with corresponding jobname and pull all files from it?

Comment: For what I am doing right now, that is accurate. the file itself is important, the name of the file, not so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT1:

```
SET JOB=JobName
SET OF=OutputFolder

START /wait NET USE Z: "\\ServerName\Sharename\ArchiveFolder" password password_here /USER:domainname\username /P:NO
PUSHD Z:\
FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%A IN (`DIR /b /a:d /s ^| FIND /I "%JOB%"`) DO (
 FOR /R %%F IN (%%A) DO (
  COPY /Y "%%~fF" "%OF%"
 )
)
POPD
```

It basically locates each subdirectory of ArchiveFolder that includes the JobName in it, then digs into each one that it finds to copy the files out of them.

EDIT2:

Added NET USE to access your network share to perform tasks on the files. If your local machine already has the UNC assigned to a driveletter, you can remove the NET USE command line and change Z: to the assigned driveletter.

Comment: hmm... this seems close, but not quite I don't think.  I clarified in my comments above.

Comment: I tried this (altering the SETs to support command line arguments in a batch file) but I didn't mention that the archive folder is on a UNC share.  That was an issue; so were spaces in the folder paths but I think I have that one under control

Comment: ugh... how about just using the path in the `dir` command?  is there a reason this cannot be done?

Comment: Since CMD does not support UNC paths, you have to use special commands to reach it (PUSHD/POPD). You can perform DIR against \\server\sharename\folder but you can't perform commands in it without making it your %CD%. If you are already connected to the share and it is assigned a driveletter, remove the `START /wait NET USE Z: "\\ServerName\Sharename\ArchiveFOlder"` etc. line and replace Z: with the assigned driveletter on your local machine.

Comment: meh... this defeats my idea of "straightforward".  I could do this with one line in a BASH shell.  Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /R %%v IN (job*.xml) DO COPY "%%v" c:\out\
```